# Authenticate a user in an ASP.NET MVC web application by calling an external ASP.NET Web Api service

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I'm planning on making a restful web service using ASP.NET Web Api. A number of ASP.NET MVC web applications and possibly native apps will consume the service. The service will use ASP.NET Identity to authorise requests/users. I can see how I would use the service with native apps by passing a token with each request.

My issue is with any ASP.NET MVC apps that consume the service, how will I mark a user as logged in after making a request to the service?

Here's what I'd like, is it possible?

- User isn't logged in, redirected to log in page
- User submits form which calls MVC controller in the app
- The controller makes a call to the web service
- The web service returns the id, name and roles of the user (JSON maybe?)
- This is where I'm stuck: The ASP.NET MVC web application then marks the user as logged in for the whole MVC web app. The role will be used in any authorize attributes on any controllers/actions. The ASP.NET MVC web app will also be able to remember the user via a cookie and log them in automatically in the future.

Comment: Not a huge big deal, but it's ASP.NET MVC, not ASP MVC.

Comment: I think what you're doing is possible. When the MVC app gets an affirmative/positive response from the webapi call, then set a cookie within the MVC app's controller's action. But you might want to consider doing away with the cookie and set something on the webapi side like a generated token then use this token on every request on the MVC app to check for authorization. Kinda precursor to a single sign on solution.

Answer (score 0):

To set the cookie you just need:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(USERNAME, true /*rememberMe*/);
```

This solve your authentication issue. Authorization - determining what a user can and cannot do   - is another story. You need to cache the roles a user is in somewhere and check them as needed.